# Is it possible to create a button where the command also uses that button itself as one of the arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so I want to make a button which has a command that requires that button itself to be passed in as one of the arguments. This is a simple snippet of my code:

```
self.buttonExcel2 = tk.Button(self, text = 'A', command 
 = self.clicked(self.buttonExcel2))
```

I know that this can't work because it is referencing something that doesn't exist yet(hence an AttributeError), but is there any way to make this possible?

Thanks

Comment: It already doesn't work because what you have written means "*call `self.clicked(self.buttonExcel2)` now*, and use *the result* as the `command` callback". Fortunately, the easiest way to solve that problem also solves the self-reference problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `command` parameter should be a callable, not the result of a call.

Perhaps you meant to use a `lambda`:

```py
self.buttonExcel2 = tk.Button(self, text = 'A', command = lambda:self.clicked(self.buttonExcel2))
```